# Determine the size of a conductive medium

Tags: electricity, electric-circuits, electric-current, voltage

Are there any measurable characteristics that would allow one to discern the size of a conductive medium?

Say I apply the same voltage to a two foot long wire and a four foot long wire.  Is there anything I could physically measure to determine the difference in relative size of the mediums?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you know something about what is surrounding your wire (like it's very far from any other conductors or it's a known distance above a ground plane) you could determine its length from its rf resonances. This would most readily be done with a network analyzer, although a more primitive setup with just a synthesizer and a vector voltmeter or an [SWR meter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SWR_meter) or even a [Wien bridge](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wien_bridge) could be used.

If you restrict the discussion to a wire above a ground plane, (or in another structure that forms a transmission line), then [time domain reflectometry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time-domain_reflectometry) could be used to find the length. This technique involves sending a pulse along the wire and using an oscilloscope to measure the time it takes for a reflected pulse to return to the launch point.

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't you measure the current? Resistance has the equation $R = p \dfrac{l}{A}$ where $p$ is the electrical resistivity, $l$ is the length and $A$ is the cross-sectional area. This formula shows resistance is directly proportional to the length of the resistor, and inversely proportional to the cross-sectional area. By hooking a known voltage across resistors of different sizes and utilising an ammeter, (and the equation $V = IR$) knowledge can be gained on the length and cross sectional areas of the resistors you are measuring.